# Stuck with this second derivative from first principles

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

It is given that

1. $a \in (0, \infty)$ and $f(a)=0$
2. $f(x)$ satisfies $x^2 f''(x) + xf'(x) -(x^2+1)f(x) =0$ for $x \in (0, \infty)$

The interval $I \subset \mathbb R$ contains $a$ and $f$ is differentiable once on $I$. It is also given that $f$ is twice differentiable at $a$. How do I prove that $$f''(a) = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac {f(a+h) - 2 f(a) + f(a-h)}{h^2}?$$

I tried using the "definition" of 2nd order derivative using limits, but could not proceed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'm going to show is a general result. It says :

> Suppose $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an open interval containing $a$ . Let $f : I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function on $I$ , and $f''(a)$ exists. Then : $$f''(a) = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac {f(a+h) - 2 f(a) + f(a-h)}{h^2}$$

Here's a proof :

\begin{align*}
&\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac {f(a+h) - 2 f(a) + f(a-h)}{h^2}\\
&\stackrel{(\#)}{=} \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac {f'(a+h) - f'(a-h)}{2h}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac {f'(a+h) - f'(a)}{h} + \frac{1}{2}\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac {f'(a) - f'(a-h)}{h}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} f''(a) + \frac{1}{2} f''(a)\\
& = f''(a)\\
\end{align*}
Here, the equality marked by $(\#)$ is due to L'Hôpital's Rule.

---

Please let me know if this answers your query or not.

Comment: thank you! spent too much time trying to figure out what that ODE is for.